# Passing & Interpreting Parameters - Dynamic Handlers

Tags: c#, .net, events, observer-pattern

I have a relatively dynamic event process and I need to be able to interpret parameters passed to a dynamic handler, but I am having trouble doing just that.

Please note that the code below is 100% functional as is. It simply needs to be adjusted to meet requirements.

Below is a simple class that defines an Action and Event. The OnLeftClickEvent() method receives an object[] of args which due to event constraints, must be encapsulated in EventArgs.

```
public class SomeSubscriber : SubscriberBase
{
    private Logger<SomeSubscriber> debug = new Logger<SomeSubscriber>();

    public Action LeftClickAction;
    public event EventHandler LeftClickEvent;

    public SomeSubscriber()
    {
        LeftClickAction += OnLeftClickEvent;
    }

    public void OnLeftClickEvent(params object[] args)
    {
        AppArgs eventArgs = new AppArgs(this, args);

        if(LeftClickEvent != null) LeftClickEvent(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

On the receiving end is the class that implements the dynamic handler and triggers the event:

```
public class EventControllBase : _MonoControllerBase
{
    private Logger<EventControllBase> debug = new Logger<EventControllBase>();

    SomeSubscriber subscriber;

    private void Start()
    {
        subscriber = new SomeSubscriber();

        subscriber.AddHandler("LeftClickEvent", e =>
        {
            debug.LogWarning( string.Format("Received {0} from {1} ", e[1], e[0]) );
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {   // Trigger events.
            subscriber.InvokeDelegate("LeftClickAction", (object) new object[]{ this, Input.mousePosition });
        }
    }
}
```

In the Start() method I define a dynamic handler and in Update() it is triggered and desired data is passed.

e[1] is obviously of type EventArgs (AppArgs:EventArgs to be specific) but I'm not sure how to access the members to get data within the instance. I've tried casting but it was a no go.

Here is the body of AppArgs if it helps:

```
public class AppArgs : EventArgs
{
public object sender {get; private set;}
private object[] _args;

public AppArgs(object sender, object[] args)
{
    this.sender = sender;
    this._args = args;
}

public object[] args()
{
    return this._args;
}
}
```

**Dynamic Handler**

```
public static class DynamicHandler
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Invokes a static delegate using supplied parameters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetType">The type where the delegate belongs to.</param>
        /// <param name="delegateName">The field name of the delegate.</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">The parameters used to invoke the delegate.</param>
        /// <returns>The return value of the invocation.</returns>
        public static object InvokeDelegate(this Type targetType, string delegateName, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return ((Delegate)targetType.GetField(delegateName).GetValue(null)).DynamicInvoke(parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invokes an instance delegate using supplied parameters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">The object where the delegate belongs to.</param>
        /// <param name="delegateName">The field name of the delegate.</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">The parameters used to invoke the delegate.</param>
        /// <returns>The return value of the invocation.</returns>
        public static object InvokeDelegate(this object target, string delegateName, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return ((Delegate)target.GetType().GetField(delegateName).GetValue(target)).DynamicInvoke(parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a dynamic handler for a static delegate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetType">The type where the delegate belongs to.</param>
        /// <param name="fieldName">The field name of the delegate.</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function which will be invoked whenever the delegate is invoked.</param>
        /// <returns>The return value of the invocation.</returns>
        public static Type AddHandler(this Type targetType, string fieldName,
            Func<object[], object> func)
        {
            return InternalAddHandler(targetType, fieldName, func, null, false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a dynamic handler for an instance delegate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">The object where the delegate belongs to.</param>
        /// <param name="fieldName">The field name of the delegate.</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function which will be invoked whenever the delegate is invoked.</param>
        /// <returns>The return value of the invocation.</returns>
        public static Type AddHandler(this object target, string fieldName,
            Func<object[], object> func)
        {
            return InternalAddHandler(target.GetType(), fieldName, func, target, false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Assigns a dynamic handler for a static delegate or event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetType">The type where the delegate or event belongs to.</param>
        /// <param name="fieldName">The field name of the delegate or event.</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function which will be invoked whenever the delegate or event is fired.</param>
        /// <returns>The return value of the invocation.</returns>
        public static Type AssignHandler(this Type targetType, string fieldName,
            Func<object[], object> func)
        {
            return InternalAddHandler(targetType, fieldName, func, null, true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Assigns a dynamic handler for a static delegate or event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">The object where the delegate or event belongs to.</param>
        /// <param name="fieldName">The field name of the delegate or event.</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function which will be invoked whenever the delegate or event is fired.</param>
        /// <returns>The return value of the invocation.</returns>
        public static Type AssignHandler(this object target, string fieldName, Func<object[], object> func)
        {
            return InternalAddHandler(target.GetType(), fieldName, func, target, true);
        }

        private static Type InternalAddHandler(Type targetType, string fieldName,
            Func<object[], object> func, object target, bool assignHandler)
        {
            Type delegateType;
            var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                               (target == null ? BindingFlags.Static : BindingFlags.Instance);
            var eventInfo = targetType.GetEvent(fieldName, bindingFlags);
            if (eventInfo != null && assignHandler)
                throw new ArgumentException("Event can be assigned.  Use AddHandler() overloads instead.");

            if (eventInfo != null)
            {
                delegateType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
                var dynamicHandler = BuildDynamicHandler(delegateType, func);
                eventInfo.GetAddMethod(true).Invoke(target, new Object[] { dynamicHandler });
            }
            else
            {
                var fieldInfo = targetType.GetField(fieldName);
                                                    //,target == null ? BindingFlags.Static : BindingFlags.Instance);
                delegateType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
                var dynamicHandler = BuildDynamicHandler(delegateType, func);
                var field = assignHandler ? null : target == null
                                ? (Delegate)fieldInfo.GetValue(null)
                                : (Delegate)fieldInfo.GetValue(target);
                field = field == null
                            ? dynamicHandler
                            : Delegate.Combine(field, dynamicHandler);
                if (target != null)
                    target.GetType().GetField(fieldName).SetValue(target, field);
                else
                    targetType.GetField(fieldName).SetValue(null, field);
                    //(target ?? targetType).SetFieldValue(fieldName, field);
            }
            return delegateType;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dynamically generates code for a method whose can be used to handle a delegate of type 
        /// <paramref name="delegateType"/>.  The generated method will forward the call to the
        /// supplied <paramref name="func"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="delegateType">The delegate type whose dynamic handler is to be built.</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function which will be forwarded the call whenever the generated
        /// handler is invoked.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Delegate BuildDynamicHandler(this Type delegateType, Func<object[], object> func)
        {
            var invokeMethod = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
            var parameters = invokeMethod.GetParameters().Select(parm =>
                Expression.Parameter(parm.ParameterType, parm.Name)).ToArray();
            var instance = func.Target == null ? null : Expression.Constant(func.Target);
            var convertedParameters = parameters.Select(parm => Expression.Convert(parm, typeof(object))).Cast<Expression>().ToArray();
            var call = Expression.Call(instance, func.Method, Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), convertedParameters));
            var body = invokeMethod.ReturnType == typeof(void)
                ? (Expression)call
                : Expression.Convert(call, invokeMethod.ReturnType);
            var expr = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, body, parameters);
            return expr.Compile();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `Subscriber` class doesn't have an `AddHandler` method, so this isn't going to work at the moment. You could use `subscriber.LeftClickEvent += ...` - but to be honest it's not clear why you've got a `Subscriber` class at all. What's it adding over what .NET already provides with delegates and events?

Comment: @Jon It's probably inherited from `SubscriberBase`. @Xerosigma Can you include the implementation of `AddHandler`?

Comment: @MikePrecup: Ah, missed that, yes. I'm still not at all clear what the purpose of this is though... it looks like it's reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @MikePrecup I have added the implementation of AddHandler at the very bottom, sorry for the misdirection. And thank you for you time.

Comment: @JonSkeet To explain the pattern, My Subscriber class will be able to capture arguments in the OnLeftClickEvent() method before the Handler is triggered. This way I can run object specific logic first then get the result/outcome I need back into the caller. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Thanks! Good read as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve my issue, below are all the modifications I made to the code above:

First off I made some slight modifications to AppArgs that are pretty self explanatory:

```
public class AppArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object sender {get; private set;}
    public object[] args {get; private set;}

    public AppArgs(object sender, object[] args)
    {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.args = args;
    }
}
```

Next step was to figure out how to properly cast my EventArgs object[] back to an AppArgs:

In **EventControllBase.Start()**

```
    private void Start()
    {
        subscriber = new SomeSubscriber();

        subscriber.AddHandler("LeftClickEvent", e =>
        {   
            debug.LogWarning( string.Format("Received {0} from {1} ", ( (AppArgs)e[1] ).args[1], e[0]) );
            return true;
        });
    }
```

To clarify, I simply had to cast e[1] in the proper manner like so: ( (AppArgs)e[1] )

I can now freely access the members of AppArgs the way I need to.
Thank you all for your help, it is very much appreciated.